# System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits

What I am trying to do is to set a date in my date field and also update the object. I am using the class below to do so which works just fine in my sanbox but in production I am getting this error:

> System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

```
public with sharing class updateObject{
    public  List<NRProducts__c>  values;
    public PageReference updateObject() {
        values=[SELECT Refreshed_Date__c FROM NRProducts__c ];
        for (NRProducts__c s :values){
           s.Refreshed_Date__c =Date.today();
         } 
        update values;
        return null;                  
    }    
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page showheader="false" controller="updateObject" sidebar="false">
<apex:form> 
<apex:commandButton action="{!updateObject}" value="Update"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too many SOQL rows returned (limit exception) - 50001](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/too-many-soql-rows-returned-limit-exception-50001)

Comment: Same error: yes, bit slightly different context. (If not using batch, the solution is to use batch. If getting that while using batch, the solution is to tweek batch sizes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're running into this on production, because you have much more data there than in your sandbox. This is a limit which is a bit harder to test against and discover in advance. You'd do well to integrate it into your salesforce developer conscious.

> total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries =  50,000

You will need to use [Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm), in which the 50k limit counts per batch execution

> These limits count for each Apex transaction. For Batch Apex, these
>   limits are reset for each execution of a batch of records in the
>   execute method.

This is clearly stated in the [limit documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). Salesforce enforces these rules to "force" us to use scaleable and resource friendly implementation patterns.

Comment: Samuel, Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with Batch apex, could you please help me with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've added a documentation starting point. It's invoking an asynchronous process in which batches of data are processed through your execution method separately. (i assume to minimize the memory heap required for the execution)

Comment: Samuel, do you think that the example applies in my case, if so how do I link my button in the VF page with it? Thank you in advance!!!"The following class uses batch Apex to reassign all accounts owned by a specific user to a different user.: [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm)

Comment: well, that's an example. the point is that you'll need to shift your solution design to a different approach. You should be able to schedule or kick of a batch process from an apex controller. (do know that only a certain amount of parallel batches can be ran).

Comment: Samuel, one more question. Let's say that I was able to modify the batch apex example, then how do I run this batch?

Comment: Use the Database.executeBatch  method, it's referenced and there are some examples on that page.

Comment: That's ok. Know that you can mark any answer to your own questions as the accepted answer by clickign the V icon below the up/down and score on the left side of the answer. This will indicate to other users that this has been solved.  And feel free to make new questions if you get stuck developing the batch apex, you can always refer back to this one.

Comment: I am so new in apex, and I found so much support in this site from awesome people like you...I hope someday I will be helping others. Thanks again!

Comment: It are kind words like those that keep everyone going :) thanks