# SOQL: Too many query rows even when only 1 is returned

Tags: trigger, soql, governorlimits

My question is in addition to the issue described here: [System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28228/system-limitexception-too-many-query-rows-50001)

What I don't understand is that **my query only returns 1 row** so how is it possible that I'm hitting a limit?

`SELECT Id, CampaignId, ContactId, LeadId, F2F_Activity_ID__c, F2F_Activity_Subject__c, F2F_Activity_Date__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE ContactId = '003d000001wfzTe'`

There are 350,000+ CampaignMember items but my `WHERE` statement returns only 1 and is on ContactId (lookup field) which I believe is indexed. I have tried putting SOQL in a loop as [suggested here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm) as well and I still get `System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001`

All post on this topic mention setting a limit below 50k which I have tried and it works considering I will likely never have a single contact Id that has more than 10k campaign members. But the question is WHY does LIMIT fix this problem? The SOQL is still going to search all 350k+ CampaignMembers.

> Note: Developer Console returns 1 row, but execute anonymous returns 50k+ (same SOQL)

Comment: This seems like it could be a visibility issue. Perhaps there are 50k+ but only 1 that you have access to.

Comment: I have full access and this query is looking by 1 Contact Id, (`003d000001wfzTe`). If I remove the `WHERE` then yes 350k+ get returned. It would seem more likely that the `ContactId` field is not indexed but the documentation makes it appear it is so unless anyone else has insight about this I don't think that's the case

Comment: for grins, did you look at the `query explain` in Developer Console?

Comment: The question you should answer is where this query is? Is it just this query(execute anonymous ) or is it part of transaction?

Comment: So this SOQL happens in a afterInsert/afterUpdate trigger handler. But my result from the developer console is a anonymous SOQL (in the query editor). I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `query explain` in DC.

Answer (score 0):

question is asked a while back...

System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001 , may need not be caused by single SOQL statement. In DC, you have executed a single SOQL Statement, but During the trasaction, the query result from multiple SOQL results can add up to more than 50000 records, resulting in above said error.