# I am trying to Show the Records based on Postcode using Geolocation Distance method

Tags: apex

I am trying to Show the Records based on Postcode in the VF Page which has a Distance Filter as 10,15,25,50 and 100 miles.

It works perfectly fine till 25 but then fails.

```
If(postObj.Geolocation__c != null){
                for(postcode__c obj :  [SELECT Geolocation__c,Name ,Id , Geolocation__Latitude__s 
                                        FROM postcode__c WHERE DISTANCE(Geolocation__c, GEOLOCATION(:latitude,:longitude), 'mi') < :distance LIMIT 50000]){
                    postalcodeIds.add(obj.Id);
                }           
           }
```

Postcode is a Object which has 2 Million Records in SF.

Errro Message - Too many query rows: 50001
Error is in expression '{!searchCall}' in page searchpage: Class.Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext: line 41, column 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28228/system-limitexception-too-many-query-rows-50001)

Comment: @PrzemysławTamoń, The Reason I can't use Batch Class as mentioned its a Search Page and batch would delay in the Results to show up!

Comment: Then his one might help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/794/how-to-query-more-than-50000-records-in-apex-and-bind-it-in-vf-page-in-jqgrid-an?rq=1